# Get hudson to checkout source to a specific directory

Tags: svn, continuous-integration, hudson, continuous

This seems like a simple task but for the life of me I can't get Hudson to checkout my source to a specific directory.
I can checkout the source using svn on the command line.
I tried specifying the Local Module setting under source code management but no dice.

I set it to c:\source\trunk and I get this when i run the build.

```
Started by user anonymous
Checking out http://mysvnserver/trunk
java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
    at java.io.Win32FileSystem.canonicalize(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalFile(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:742)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:660)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:753)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:735)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:653)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:601)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1082)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.checkout(AbstractBuild.java:479)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:411)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1280)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:293)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:137)
Finished: FAILURE
```

When i try to set a relative path it says I can't use absolute directories.
i.e \source\trunk

All i want to have happen is hudson checkout my source to c:\source\trunk

Answer (score 5):

As sbi already said:

> Paths like the SVN are **relative to the**
>    **Workspace root**. At least that's what
>   the help for "Local module directory"
>   says on the Job configuration page.

When you start a path with '\' than it means that the path is absolute. You have two options.

1. Define a custom workspace for your job. This could be c:\source and the checkout of the source would be to trunk (or leave it empty if checking out your svn url ends with '/trunk'.
2. check it out to your standard workspace and then copy it to C:\source\trunk.

BTW, I would favor the second option, because I try to avoid the custom workspace at almost all costs.

Answer (score 1):

Paths like the SVN are ***relative to the Workspace root***. At least that's what the help for "Local module directory" says on the Job configuration page.

Answer (score 0):

The other workaround is to create MAster-Slave config in the same system on which Hudson is running. Create a slave on the same machine and point to the location where yu want yur projet to checkout in the Slave configuration