# jenkins: java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have installed jenkins-1.594 into my windows 7 64 bit machine using msi file. It uses Java 1.6 and Maven to build my code from SVN. When I ran the build for the first time I got below exception and build failed.

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace D:\workspace
java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
    at java.io.Win32FileSystem.canonicalize(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalFile(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.UpdateUpdater$TaskImpl.getSvnCommandToUse(UpdateUpdater.java:79)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.UpdateUpdater$TaskImpl.perform(UpdateUpdater.java:130)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:161)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.perform(SubversionSCM.java:1004)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:985)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:961)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:981)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:959)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:910)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:845)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1265)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:622)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:528)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1759)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:531)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Check out your configuration (Local module directory) and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866732/get-hudson-to-checkout-source-to-a-specific-directory

Comment: What's your svn full url?

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem when using Gthub as SCM.

After trying "Wipe Out Current Workspace" resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

This could be an issue with drive permission. Are you able to create files on the drive manually? Try installing Jenkins on other drive (if one is available)!!